# Running Flash (AS3) code in Haxe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I am starting out developing in [Haxe](http://haxe.org) in combination with [OpenFl](http://www.openfl.org/), and am in a situation where I need to be able to run *Flash/AS3* code in a Haxe program which is being compiled to Flash anyway.

I know I could use the command `lime build -as3 as3source/` and then edit *that* code and manually insert the *AS3* code I need to run, but I would prefer not doing that if I can.

#### Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile your AS3 code into a separate `swf` or `swc` and then use `-swf-lib` to use it from Haxe.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would compile the AS3 code, (I am on a Mac _- i.e. No FlashDevelop -_ and cant afford to purchase Flash Professional)?

Comment: @bobberson12 Use the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) to compile AS3 code from a terminal window. I believe the mxmlc compiler creates both swf files and swc libraries.

Comment: `mxmlc` creates SWFs (aka Flash executables), `compc` creates SWCs (aka Flash libraries).  =)  You can use the free AIR SDK, Adobe Flex SDK, or Apache Flex SDK - they all include mxmlc and compc.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a build script which enters the code in combination with the command for you, if you just want to avoid doing it manually, but I belive that´s the kind of answer you want.

I just find build script very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [this article](http://haxe.org/doc/flash/usingas3classes), some major options are described there (including tools for converting AS3 code to Haxe and technique with -swf-lib).

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll go check it out.

Comment: I would _thumbs-up_, but I have no rep on StackOverflow.